# How to use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to capture a screenshot of iPhone using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avfoundation

Trying to extend AVCaptureVidioPreviewLayer from AVFoundation to capture a screenshot of iPhone with the following swift code always return a blank white UIImage, although with the correct size. Could anyone please help what's the correct way to do this?

```
extension AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        if let connection = self.connection, connection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
            let currentTransform = self.affineTransform()
            context.concatenate(currentTransform)
        }
        self.render(in: context)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenshot
    }
}
```

Comment: This may not be trivial. Certain elements (like `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`) may render in a way that doesn't touch the UIKit stack or doesn't render reliably in a forced synchronous way like this. Any element that renders to Metal might be susceptible to this. Instead, you'd need to figure out how to get the raw frames directly from your video source to render to your context